# Low FPS on DotA2

Tags: games, steam, framerate

I have recently changed to Ubuntu 16.04, installed Steam and DotA, updated my NVIDIA driver, using minimal configuration, but still my maximum frames per second is 30.

My specs are as follows:

- Geoforce GT 630M/PCIe/SSE2
- Intel Core i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHZ x 8
- 8 GB of ram

I used to play DotA on Windows with 40+ FPS and better configurations. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back your driver version to an older one. You may also want to monitor your frequency to make sure your not getting stuck in power saving mode and the graphics card is being fully utilised.

Comment: I tried an old driver and Im sure that it's not on power saving mode, but still 10-30 FPS :(

Comment: Assuming your hardware is operating as normal (GPU and CPU operating at max frequency) and assuming your graphics settings are still the same. Its probably just a bad implementation of the games features for your OS. You probably have to just deal with it or roll back your OS :\

Comment: No problem anytime, i hope you find a solution or at least a decent compromise  :)